# how to get the maximum file size limit of fileupload control in asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I want to check the file size limit for my file upload control .

the html code is here:

```
<input id="uplTheFile" style="WIDTH: 318px; HEIGHT: 22px" type="file" size="80" name="uplTheFile" runat="server">
```

i have searched in code but failed to get.here is the attribute named `size = 80` .
i have tried to searched on net but only able to see that it is optional.i am not sure whether it is used for defining the file size.

please suggest.

Comment: check maxRequestLength in your web.config. default is 4MB. <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="4096" />

Comment: @Sandeep he is asking for the filesize not the maximum allowed request.

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath i am assuming from his description that she is facing some problem when uploading file with some size and want to check where file upload size limit is specified.

Comment: are you getting any error while uploading file?

Comment: yes Sandeep, i am not getting the location where it is specified but , i have tried to upload the file with greater than 4mb and it gives the error specifying "maximum file size exceeded"

Comment: thanks Sandeep for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the [HttpRuntimeSection.MaxRequestLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength(v=vs.110).aspx) property for the limiting the upload file size.

> The maximum request size in kilobytes. The default size is 4096 KB (4
>   MB).

You can set that *maxRequestLength* in `web.config`, the following example sets *20MB* limit in web.config.

```
<system.web>
     <!-- ....   -->
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="20480"/>
     <!-- ....   -->  
</system.web>
```

> Specifies the limit for the input stream buffering threshold, in KB.
>   This limit can be used to prevent denial of service attacks that are
>   caused, for example, by users posting large files to the server. You
>   can read more about HTTPRuntime in this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.85).aspx).